# Laravel 6 - How to get the value from controller's compact array in view/blade?

Tags: php, laravel

I am passing an array using compact from my Controller to a blade and I want to access them one by one in my view / blade template but I am always receiving this error:

[image]

Here's the content of my compact array:

[image]

Here's my snippet source code from the **Controller**:

```
//dd($flight_book_details);
    $flight_book_details = $request->all(); 
    return view('auth.register', compact('flight_book_details'));
```

And here's my snippet source code in the **view** / **blade template**:

```
<h2>
@foreach($flight_book_details as $flight_book_detail)
    {{$flight_book_detail->seat_quantity}}  //Trying to access the 'seat_quantity'
@endforeach
</h2>
```

> **Question:** Is there any other way to access the values from the compact in view?

Comment: @Daan i tried and it gave me this error: Illegal string offset 'seat_quantity'

Comment: Remove the loop and access it like `$flight_book_details['seat_quantity']`

Comment: You shouldn't post screenshots of [code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) or [exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/), copy and paste them into your question as text, instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to access `seat_quantity` you do not need to `foreach` loop through it,

```php
<h2>
    {{$flight_book_details['seat_quantity']}}
</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are getting all data.use array. $flight_book_details->seat_quantity used when data get an object

```
{{$flight_book_details['seat_quantity']}}
```